# Display 3dsmax models in web browser

Tags: javascript, maya, 3ds

I have some 3d models written in 3dmax/maya/cad/4dcinema , i wand to display them in my website so user can rotate the model and inspect it .

i have found this on the internet http://replimat.com/thingiview/examples/client_side_ajax.html i think it will work IF i could somehow convert those models from 3dmax/maya/cad/3dcinema to OBJ/STL .

is there any converter available for linux ? or any other method to display those models in web browser without having to install anything on the browser ?
thank you .

Comment: Write a WebGL-based viewer, and become rich and famous. // ontopic: there are no such viewers yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your model in maya to a wavefront(.obj) file. Then you could use a library like three.js, along with this script to load and view .obj files within the browser

[obj to three.js json](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/convert_obj_three.py)

Programming the moveable camera can also be done using the library. If you want to use the default formats, it will be tricky as you may need to write the parser yourself if there isn't one and the spec is freely available.

Comment: any unix softwares to convert stuff to .obj ?

Comment: Wings3D has a built in converter to waveform, but I am not sure if it will accept 3dmax/maya's default file format. But I am sure there should be a common export/import format in 3dmax/maya  and Wings3d

Comment: Blender can convert many files into Wavefront OBJ.  There is also always the option of using VTK to load a mesh and export it as OBJ.

Answer (score 1):

I remember 3dsmax support obj format, regarding the other apps I don't remember.
Anyway, you can use try this [tool](http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/LinuxGuidesByBlaze/apps3Dtools/3D_viewers-converters/3DviewersANDconverters_intro.htm), you didn't mention which formats you saved from 3dsmax/maya/cad/3dcinema but it supports many format.

Comment: Hi Lior , have you checked the link in my question , there's a rotating 3d object , try moving it . i want to use such viewer to view 3d object right from the browser . 3d objects i want to view are default formats for 3dsmax/maya/cad/3dcinema

Answer (score 1):

For the widest range of existing solutions you won't beat converting your models to [VRML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML).

This format has plugins that support browsers as far back as IE 3 and Netscape 4. There are a large number of [free and commercial plugins](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/vrml/tools/viewers_and_browsers/) that handle this format. If you don't want the user to rely on plugins there are also java applet based viewers.

There should be a variety of tools that will convert your models to VRML as well, even if you have to save to an intermediate format first.

The main downside of VRML is lack of fancy new features like shaders, bones and complex texturing but whether those things are necessary all depends what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this webservice http://showwebgl.com it does not support 3dsmax directly but you could export your model into obj or collada then upload it. Have a look at the faq if it fits your need. http://showwebgl.com/faq

Comment: Thank you , but the problem is i want to display the models in my website :)

Comment: You can embed it with the iframe code, and it will be on your website

Comment: Will be a bad idea for my site members

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. - http://www.thoro.de/page/3dnp-introduction-en

Visitors don't need to install anything on their browser, just click and go. Your 3d model loading takes some time, for that a progress bar is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using X3DOM. It allows you to script interaction with the 3D object using javascript.

1. First export from 3ds Max as VRML.
2. Convert the VRML to X3DOM by copying and pasting the code into [this online converter](http://doc.instantreality.org/tools/x3d_encoding_converter/).
3. Simply insert the converted code into your web page where desired.

Because the 3D model is now part of the dom you can manipulate it with javascript and style it with CSS. Here's an [example](http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom_camBindAnim.html).