# Play 3dmx or maya in the browser

Tags: browser, maya

i hava many obj model files, i wand to display them in my website so user can rotate the model and inspect it .

is there any browser plugin? 
or any other method to display those models in web browser with install anything on the browser ? thank you .

---

i have found the answer "[Display 3dsmax models in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268485/display-3dsmax-models-in-web-browser)", but dit not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that as it is your website, you can have access to the source code and modify it to your own will. There are some solution offered in the link you posted.

The first one is using a javascript library like three.js to load your .obj models in a webpage. Cons: you need to do a bit a programming but that's quite easy to load an obj model in a webpage. Example with source code here: [Three.js load obj example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj)

The second one is using a webservice which will host you obj models, it will provide you a way to show your creation directly on their website or embed a model reader directly on your website. Cons: you can be limited in terms of model size, this may not be free, read terms and conditions. Example: [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/)

In both case, visitors don't need to install any browser plugin.

If you can't have access to the source code of your website, we will need more informations concerning your host, framework etc...

Comment: thank your replay. I have all the source code. Can you give me a suggestion to install the plug play it

Comment: What do you mean in your last sentence? I'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use https://clara.io/, a web-based modeling and animation package to load, edit and display models. As you can see from [this page](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/01/first-find-of-2014-scriptable-dcc-app.html) you can also create an embeddable view of models which can be rotated interactively.