# Viewing a 3d model in browser

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

I would like to know how I can go from a 3d model to a moveable in browser model. An example of this would be the roblox website. If you go to any player profile there is a character model that you can move around. My model has a .obj format. Would this format be compatible with the technology roblox uses?

Comment: You could check out https://threejs.org/. It supports obj files.

Comment: refer to the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268485/display-3dsmax-models-in-web-browser

I think this will helpful for you

Comment: @Tophat Welcome to the StackOverflow and these guidelines will help to ask questions more effectively. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your model in Maya to a wavefront(.obj) file. Then you could use a library like three.js, along with this script to load and view .obj files within the browser

obj to [three.js](https://threejs.org/) JSON

Programming the moveable camera can also be done using the library. If you want to use the default formats, it will be tricky as you may need to write the parser yourself if there isn't one and the spec is freely available.